# NetBeans, Trying to read from .txt file with scanner, FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, text, netbeans, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read characters from a text file to fill an array of objects using a scanner, within the NetBeans IDE. All of the files for the game are in the same folder, src/wizard/game. Following is my GamePanel.java class with everything but the relevant code removed:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    boolean instantiated;

    public GamePanel() {
        spaces = new Entity[width][height];
        // Tell whether entities have been instantiated yet or not
        instantiated = false;
    }

    // *** Interfacing methods ***
    // Instatntiate entites in a level from a text file
    public static void loadLevel(String l) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File level = new File(l);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(level);
        for(int y=1; y<=GamePanel.getH(); y++) {
            for(int x=1; x<=GamePanel.getW(); x++) {
                String nextIdentifier = s.next();
                switch(nextIdentifier) {
                    case("x"):
                        // Nothing
                        break;
                    case("s"):
                        new WallSandstone(x, y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // Instantiate entities here only once
        while(instantiated == false){
            try {
                loadLevel("levelOne.txt");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GamePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            instantiated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and the levelOne.txt file:

```
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x s s s s s s s s s s s s s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x s s s s s s x s s s s s s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
s s s s s s s s s s s s s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x s x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

Running this code gives the following error:

```
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: levelOne.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at wizard.game.GamePanel.loadLevel(GamePanel.java:65)
    at wizard.game.GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:97)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: You text file is obviously in the wrong place, it should be in the root folder of your project if you don't want to specify an absolute path. I don't think `The system cannot find the file specified` can get any more descriptive than it already is...

Comment: how would I go about specifying an absolute path? I would like to keep the file in its current folder with everything else if I can

Comment: You type it in.... just like always. Also, static text files do not belong with your source code.

Comment: type what in? like "wizard/game/levelOne.txt"? You can't just say "like always" because I have never worked with files or paths before and have no idea how they work in java

Comment: read a guide, this site requires you to have done a minimum amount of research on your. Simply typing "Absolute Path" into google would answer most if not all of your questions. Absolute path is not a concept unique to your game, it is ubiquitous throughout operating systems and programming

Answer (score 0):

When you try to load a file, you can try to use the following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("levelOne.txt").getFile());
```

If you don't have package specified, it will look for the fileOne.txt file start from the root folder of your class path.

```
ie .. |-/GamePanel.java
      |-/levelOne.txt
```